# How to evaluate an integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to evaluate this integral

```
Integrate[(kx^2/2)*Sin[λx], x]
```

from -pi/2(lamda) to pi/2(lamda)

Everything there is a constant, and the only variable is x.

this is the output i get

```
1/2 kx^2 x Sin[λx]
```

which i do not think is correct.

Comment: You're missing a space for multiplication between `k, \[Lambda]` and `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned by b.gatessucks: When you type `kx` it is handled by *Mathematica* as the variable `kx`. You must include a space to specify a multiplication or better, use `*` explicitly!

```
Integrate[(k x^2/2)*Sin[\[Lambda] x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]