# Mathematica Integral[] return

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am new to mathematica and while trying to find the double integral of 8-xy over -2

```
f[x_, y_] = 8 - xy;
a = -2; b = 2; c = -3; d = 3;
Integrate[f[x, y], {x, a, b}, {y, c, d}]
24 (8 - xy)
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: That should be `8 - x y`, with a space between `x` and `y`.  Variables in *Mathematica* can be more than one letter.

Comment: Is this still so when I edited in my function definition?

Comment: Yes, your definition of `f` should have `8 - x y`, not `8 - xy`.  The `xy` with the letters together are taken as the name of a single symbol, in the same way as my name "Michael" taken, not to be the product of seven people "M", "i", etc., but to be a the name of a single person.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22565/how-to-evaluate-an-integral/22567#22567

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] := 8 - x y;
Integrate[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -3, 3}]
(* 192*)
```

Comment: In my edit I added where I defined f[x,y], shouldn't it still work with the defined f[x,y]?

Comment: @JJStamp A space is needed to imply multiplcation